# Renaming PDF file downloaded from website

Tags: pdf

I have seen similar posts in the forum, but nothing with the exact same issue.

Our HR department is looking for a way to simplify the renaming process of job applications that they download from our business' website. A potential employee fills out the PDF file, and then they submit it through our website. Our HR department would then download the pdf and save them all to a folder.

What they would like is to be able to have the pdf file name generated from 3 fields inside the pdf file. First Name, Last Name, and social security number. So the file name would be something like Mike_Jefferson_345-44-4444. That name would pop up when they click on download.

This would save a lot of time as far as data entry is concerned since we are a larger sized company with over 3,000 employees. It would also reduce the errors that happen from keying this info on each form when they save it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Who maintains the code at the website level? They would be best to talk with about this I would think and especially if this is an internally hosted and supported website. Otherwise, you will likely need to use a URL web call to the site and be able to get the files that way one by one and then OCR the document (assuming that's possible) and use the values from the areas on the standard form to build the file name and rename it accordingly. If you're in Windows look into `Invoke-WebRequest` and `curl` or `wget` for Linux I believe but those are quick thoughts, it's possible regardless I think.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I will reach out to the people that maintain the website and see what their thoughts are. And I will read up on the Invoke-WebRequest and curl. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Are the PDF files filled out electronically? Then you don't need OCR, you just need to convert the PDF to raw text and find a way to extract the required information via a script. This entirely depends on the tools you have at hand (which operating system?) and how much knowledge you have about scripting.

Comment: I have very little scripting knowledge myself, but I am sure someone in the IT department has some knowledge. The PDF files are filled electronically. Windows is the OS. I thought there might be some type of software available (doesn't have to be free) that would be able to pull this data, but that was just a guess. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: The thoughts about the software would be something that would be able to do a group of PDFs at once. http://www.dropitproject.com/ is something I am going to download to test and see if it can possibly do this.

Comment: If you're software shopping, look into [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) and [GhostScript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) for help with the conversions. For getting the data content via the URL call that way then look into using [Invoke-WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest). You may still need to work with the web developers to ensure you understand what to use for the URL to call the PDF files, to authenticate passing in credentials, etc. but get to work and [edit] what you try.